# Returning Rvalue Reference and Temporary Materialization

Tags: c++, return, c++17, rvalue-reference, xvalue

Consider the following functions. I'd like answers for **C++17**.

```
MyClass&& func() {
  return MyClass{};
}

int main() {
  MyClass&& myRef = func();
}
```

Questions:

1. Is the expression `func()` an xvalue? Why?
2. Why is `myRef` a dangling reference? Or, more specifically, why is `func()` returning a dangling reference? Wouldn't returning rvalue reference cause temporary materialization, and extend the temporary object's lifetime?

Comment: "*Is the expression func() an xvalue? Why?*" ... why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`func()` is an xvalue because one of the rules of the language is that if a function is declared to have a return type of rvalue reference to object, then an expression consisting of calling that function is an xvalue . (C++17 expr.call/11).

[Temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) occurs any time a reference is bound to a prvalue.

The *result* of the function is `myRef` which is initialized by the prvalue `func()`. However if we consult the lifetime extension rules in class.temporary/6 it has:

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement  is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.

So the temporary object materialized by `func()`  is destroyed when the `return` statement completes, with no extension.